# Unable to properly configure Intel HD 510 (Skylake) graphics on Debian Jessie

Tags: debian, intel, intel-graphics, skylake, mesa

I have had this issue since I installed , and I've been trying to resolve this with my limited experience with linux (which I have been using for ~9 months now).

Internal graphics on debian do not work. I can load X. Almost everything else gives an error like this:

```
name_of_application: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1: undefined symbol: _glapi_tls_Dispatch
```

I am sure this is not an issue from the motherboard, because I have checked every setting. Windows 8 works fine, it detects everything without any problems. I've tested a few video games, they all run well.

I managed to circumvent this problem for a few months by installing
   libgl1-mesa-swx11
over
   libgl1-mesa-glx

That package uses a software decoder and although it manages to crcumvent the issue, the performance is not very good. I've decided to switch back to libgl1-mesa-glx to solve this issue. T

```
# dmidecode --type baseboard
# dmidecode 3.0
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.0 present.

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 15 bytes
Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: MSI
    Product Name: B150M PRO-VDH (MS-7982)
    Version: 1.0
    Serial Number: G416029796
    Asset Tag: Default string
    Features:
        Board is a hosting board
        Board is replaceable
    Location In Chassis: Default string
    Chassis Handle: 0x0003
    Type: Motherboard
    Contained Object Handles: 0

Handle 0x0039, DMI type 41, 11 bytes
Onboard Device
    Reference Designation:  Onboard IGD
    Type: Video
    Status: Enabled
    Type Instance: 1
    Bus Address: 0000:00:02.0

Handle 0x003A, DMI type 41, 11 bytes
Onboard Device
    Reference Designation:  Onboard LAN
    Type: Ethernet
    Status: Enabled
    Type Instance: 1
    Bus Address: 0000:00:19.0

Handle 0x003B, DMI type 41, 11 bytes
Onboard Device
    Reference Designation:  Onboard 1394
    Type: Other
    Status: Enabled
    Type Instance: 1
    Bus Address: 0000:03:1c.2
```

~

```
# inxi -Gxx
Graphics:  Card: Intel HD Graphics 510 bus-ID: 00:02.0 chip-ID: 8086:1902
           Display Server: X.org 1.18.3 drivers: intel (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
           tty size: 99x25 Advanced Data: N/A for root
```

~

```
# aptitude reinstall firmware-misc-nonfree xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-video-intel libegl1-mesa libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri
The following packages will be REINSTALLED:
  firmware-misc-nonfree libegl1-mesa libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx 
  xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-video-intel 
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-headers-4.8.0-0.bpo.2-amd64{u} 
  linux-headers-4.8.0-0.bpo.2-common{u} linux-kbuild-4.8{u} 
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 6 reinstalled, 3 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/12.4 MB of archives. After unpacking 30.8 MB will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] y
(Reading database ... 327171 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-headers-4.8.0-0.bpo.2-amd64 (4.8.15-2~bpo8+2) ...
Removing linux-headers-4.8.0-0.bpo.2-common (4.8.15-2~bpo8+2) ...
Removing linux-kbuild-4.8 (4.8.15-2~bpo8+2) ...
(Reading database ... 314918 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libegl1-mesa_13.0.5-1~bpo8+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libegl1-mesa:amd64 (13.0.5-1~bpo8+1) over (13.0.5-1~bpo8+1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libgl1-mesa-dri_13.0.5-1~bpo8+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 (13.0.5-1~bpo8+1) over (13.0.5-1~bpo8+1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../xserver-xorg-core_2%3a1.16.4-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking xserver-xorg-core (2:1.16.4-1) over (2:1.16.4-1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libgl1-mesa-glx_13.0.5-1~bpo8+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 (13.0.5-1~bpo8+1) over (13.0.5-1~bpo8+1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../firmware-misc-nonfree_20161130-2~bpo8+1_all.deb ...
Unpacking firmware-misc-nonfree (20161130-2~bpo8+1) over (20161130-2~bpo8+1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../xserver-xorg-video-intel_2%3a2.99.917+git20161206-1~bpo8+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking xserver-xorg-video-intel (2:2.99.917+git20161206-1~bpo8+1) over (2:2.99.917+git20161206-1~bpo8+1) ...
Processing triggers for glx-alternative-mesa (0.7.3~bpo8+1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-5) ...
Setting up libegl1-mesa:amd64 (13.0.5-1~bpo8+1) ...
Setting up libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 (13.0.5-1~bpo8+1) ...
Setting up libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 (13.0.5-1~bpo8+1) ...
Setting up xserver-xorg-core (2:1.16.4-1) ...
Setting up firmware-misc-nonfree (20161130-2~bpo8+1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up xserver-xorg-video-intel (2:2.99.917+git20161206-1~bpo8+1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.120+deb8u2) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.9.0-0.bpo.2-amd64
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_ver9_14.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_guc_ver8_7.bin for module i915
```

~

```
# glxinfo
glxinfo: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1: undefined symbol: _glapi_tls_Dispatch
```

~

```
# glxgears
glxgears: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1: undefined symbol: _glapi_tls_Dispatch
```

~

```
# inxi
CPU~Dual core Intel Pentium G4400 (-MCP-) clocked at Min:799.822Mhz Max:800.024Mhz Kernel~4.9.0-0.bpo.2-amd64 x86_64 Up~53 min Mem~1091.2/7801.4MB HDD~1000.2GB(62.4% used) Procs~165 Client~Shell inxi~2.1.28
```

cat /etc/default/grub (I removed the comments)

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=3
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="initrd=/install/initrd.gz"
GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.preliminary_hw_support=1"
edd=on
video=i915:modeset=0
```

Improperly linked files are probably the issue, but I have no clue how to resolve that. I'll provide any other logs you want.

`ldd /usr/bin/glxgears` shows

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc85b72000)
    libGLEW.so.1.10 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so.1.10 (0x00007f1665f22000)
    libGLU.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1 (0x00007f1665cb4000)
    libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f1665a40000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f166573c000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f16653f9000)
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f16651e5000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f1664e47000)
    libXmu.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXmu.so.6 (0x00007f1664c2e000)
    libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0x00007f1664a1e000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f166469d000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f1664486000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f166425a000)
    libxcb-dri3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri3.so.0 (0x00007f1664057000)
    libxcb-present.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-present.so.0 (0x00007f1663e54000)
    libxcb-sync.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-sync.so.1 (0x00007f1663c4d000)
    libxshmfence.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxshmfence.so.1 (0x00007f1663a4b000)
    libglapi.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libglapi.so.0 (0x00007f16637e3000)
    libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007f16635de000)
    libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007f16633d8000)
    libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0x00007f16631d6000)
    libxcb-glx.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0 (0x00007f1662fbd000)
    libxcb-dri2.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri2.so.0 (0x00007f1662db8000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f1662b96000)
    libXxf86vm.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0x00007f166298e000)
    libdrm.so.2 => /usr/local/lib/libdrm.so.2 (0x00007f1662780000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f1662563000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f166235f000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055b24657c000)
    libXt.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXt.so.6 (0x00007f16620f6000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f1661ef0000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f1661ceb000)
    libSM.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6 (0x00007f1661ae3000)
    libICE.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libICE.so.6 (0x00007f16618c6000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f16616c1000)
```

Comment: @StephenKitt And here's my /var/log/Xorg.0.log https://paste.debian.net/919141/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_glapi_tls_Dispatch` is defined by `libglapi.so.0`, which is in the `libglapi-mesa` package. In your case it’s also in `/usr/local/lib`, and that’s what’s picked up; in the output of `ldd /usr/bin/glxgears`:

```
libglapi.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libglapi.so.0 (0x00007f16637e3000)
```

You need to delete `/usr/local/lib/libglapi*`.

Comment: I rebooted my system after deleting these files, and every problem in my initial post has been resolved.